# python not showing values in max()

Tags: python

The following code ran in PYCHARM editor

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Train_UWu5bXk.csv')
df.min()
```

the output is not showing any value

```
C:\Users\krishna\PycharmProjects\pdproject\Scripts\python.exe
C:/Users/krishna/Python37-32/Scripts/phythonncode/load1pandas.py

Process finished with exit code 0
```

someone can help me.

Comment: `print(df.min())`?

Comment: Pycharm doesn't show non-printed lines at the end of blocks like jupyter notebooks do. You have to print something to see it's output

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved with the following code in python
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('Train_UWu5bXk.csv')
print(df.min())